# No viable overloaded '=' for assigning std::function callback as member function

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to hook a member function up to an `std::function` callback. The callback type is:

```
std::function<void(Touch*, Event*)>
```

My member function is:

```
void Game::onTouchEnded(Touch* touch, Event* event)
```

When I try to assign the callback using the following:

```
listener->onTouchEnded = bind(&Game::onTouchEnded, this);
```

I get a `No viable overloaded '='` error with several candidates. Here are the details of the one I believe to be most relevant:

```
Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 
'__bind<void (Game::*)(cocos2d::Touch *, cocos2d::Event *), Game *>'
to
'std::__1::function<void (cocos2d::Touch *, cocos2d::Event *)>'
for 1st argument`
```

I've tried several different bind() arrangements but I'm not sure what the error is telling me. The types all seem to be correct in terms of the parameters and return value so I'm not sure why it won't accept it?

Comment: Try to add two `std::placeholders`.

Comment: You need to pass the 2nd parameter

Comment: @LogicStuff @sunny1304 I have nothing else to bind, though. Those parameters will be passed to *me* in the callback. I am just binding the function to `this` so that I can use a member function as a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
listener->onTouchEnded = bind(&Game::onTouchEnded, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
```

or try a lambda function

```
listener->onTouchEnded = [this](Touch* touch, Event* event){ this->onTouchEnded(touch, event); };
```

Comment: Huh, the first one actually works! I had tried bind with only placeholders::_1, but not the second. What is that bind call actually doing?!

Comment: Oh, and the lambdas are fine -- I was already using them but wanted to switch to a member function instead. That's a good option, though.

Comment: After some more reading on bind(), I think I understand it. The two placeholders are for the Touch* and Event* parameters. For some reason I thought that the placeholder defined the position of the parameter I was passing -- the `this`. That's why I only included one when I tried it. But now I think I see what's going on!

Comment: @aardvarkk Just to add, its a long magical and mythical thing :-) ... but I am glad you understand it now

Comment: @aardvarkk `bind` simply writes something nearly identical to the lambda, while adding on some extra annoying magic if you try to `bind` recursively.  That recursive corner case leads me to *avoid* using `bind`, because it is rarely shorter or more clear than a simple lambda, and it has a chance to bite you.

Answer (score 2):

`bind` must be told what to do with parameters passed to its return value.  By default, it simply discards them.

When you pass it to the `std::function`, it tries to type-erase it.  `std::function` passes a `Touch*, Event*` to the `bind`.  `bind`'s return value discards them, and calls `(this->*&Game::onTouchEnded)()`, as you requested.  This is not a valid call, and you get an error.

The simple way to fix this is to add placeholders that say "what do do with arguments to the bind return value".  `bind` treats member functions as functions that take an extra `this` argument first.  You want:

```
(this->*&Game::onTouchEnded)(_1, _2)
```

which corresponds to:

```
std::bind(&Game::onTouchEnded, this, _1, _2)
```

---

Now this is all well and good, but really you should avoid `std::bind`.  Fully understanding it is tricky: It has strange corner cases that can bite you, or force you to needlessly type-erase, when you call it recursively.

Instead, use a lambda.  In C++11 it looks like:

```
[this](Touch* touch, Event* event){return this->onTouchEnded(touch, event);}
```

In C++14, an alternative is:

```
[this](auto&&args)->decltype(auto){return this->onTouchEnded(decltype(args)(args)...);}
```

or even:

```
template<class T, class M>
auto bind_method( T* t, M* m ) {
  return [t, m](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
    return (t->*m)(decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
bind_method(this, &Game::onTouchEnded)
```

and is a drop-in replacement to your call to `bind`.  Here, we auto-forward the arguments to the method we call, instead of having to list them explicitly.

Comment: I actually WAS using lambdas but the inlined code started to get pretty lengthy and distracting. Would you say that using a one-line lambda that just forwards the parameters to a member function is superior to calling bind directly? That's what I'm kind of gathering from your other comment above.

Comment: @aardvarkk Yes.  Any C++ developer should understand at least basic lambdas, but few C++ developers fully understand `bind`.  And a short lambda is at least as clear as a `bind`.